# Can I change keyboard shortcut in turbo c++

Tags: shortcut, turbo-c++

I use Windows 10. I'm trying to use turbo c++ but in turbo c++, I can't create # symbol shortly.

For create symbol =
Shift + 3 and after this altgr + 3 = #

How can i change this shortcut to simple one.

Comment: Can you enter `#` more easily on command line, or in Windows applications? Ie. is this problem with Turbo C specifically, or with your whole environment?

Comment: In Windows it's just altrgr + 3 if I remember correctly. I think problem is about altgr, altrgr is not working until I wrote shift +3(I depended this idea to a post about altrgr is not directly works)

Comment: Possibly unhelpful, but consider switching to US English keyboard layout for programming (Windows supports easy switching between layouts). Many characters needed in programming are easier to type when you don't need AltGr at all. This is what I use for programming, though I need to write comments in English too so there are no issues with them.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes it's worked on us english keyboard layout.